# user interface freezed when using concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyside

I think the user interface shouldn't be freezed when using concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor here, but it doesn't meet my expectations,anyone can explain why ? any other solutions here to not let user interface freezed?

```
import sys   
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import time

import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.tmall.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://huawei.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://jd.com/', 
        'http://weibo.com/?c=spr_web_360_hao360_weibo_t001', 
        'http://www.sina.com.cn/', 
        'http://taobao.com',
        'http://www.amazon.cn/?tag=360daohang-23', 
        'http://www.baidu.com/', 
        'http://www.pconline.com.cn/?ad=6347&360hot_site']

# Retrieve a single page and report the url and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    conn = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout)
    return conn.readall()




class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.speedCalculate)

#        self.timerC = QTimer();
#        self.timerC.timeout.connect(self.speedCalculate)
#        self.timerC.start(1000)




    def speedCalculate(self):#compare with for loop
        t1=time.clock()
        # We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(URLS)) as executor:
            # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
            future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
                url = future_to_url[future]
                try:
                    data = future.result()
                except Exception as exc:
                    print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
                else:
                    print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))

        t2=time.clock()
        print('t2-t1-------------', t2-t1)
#        
#        for url in URLS:
#            data=load_url(url, 60)
#            print(url, len(data))
#        
#        t3=time.clock()
#        print('t3-t2-------------', t3-t2)
    #    
if __name__ == '__main__':                         
    app =QApplication(sys.argv)      
    splitter =MainWindow()   
    splitter.show()      
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two things you need to know:

1. Slots are called in the thread of the object, which means in this case `speedCalculate` is called on the main thread.
2. `concurrent.futures.as_completed` returns an iterator over completed futures, which means a for loop over this would not finish until all the futures are completed.

As a consequence, your `speedCalculate` method returns only after all the downloads are finished, blocking your application event loop.

What you should do instead is do all the work which you currently do in `speedCalculate` in a different method, say `_speedCalculate` and call that in a new thread within the `speedCalculate` slot.

Something like:

```
def speedCalculate(self):
    threading.Thread(target=self._speedCalculate).start()

def _speedCalculate(self):#compare with for loop
    t1=time.clock()
    # We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(URLS)) as executor:
        # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
        future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
            url = future_to_url[future]
            try:
                data = future.result()
            except Exception as exc:
                print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
            else:
                print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))

    t2=time.clock()
    print('t2-t1-------------', t2-t1)
```

Comment: And not only that, the GIL will prevent UI updates until the computation is finished (in this case there is a chance it can keep up because the GIL is released when doing I/O, like fetching URLs through the network).

Comment: I don't think the GIL is an issue here at all, because no cpu intensive thread is running which will preempt thread switching by of reacquiring GIL immediately after releasing it, and all python io methods release the GIL.

Comment: 1) you say Slots are called in the thread of the object,then slot corresponds to the  finished() signal of QThread is called in which thread ?  2)Does user interfere temporarily freezed will cause the event loop not run ?

Comment: 1) Unless you connect using ``Qt::DirectConnection`` ( http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum , more threading info at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html ), the slot will be called in the thread of the object (i.e. QObject.thread(), which is normally the thread in which the receiver of the slot was created, unless you called QObject.moveToThread())

Comment: 2) Event loop being blocked is the cause of the user interface freeze. In this case the main event loop calls your slot `speedCalculate()`, which does not return soon enough for the event loop to continue processing other events like drawing the UI.